# custom Environment Variables not available in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, operating-system, pyspark, environment-variables

I write a project in pyspark with `main.py` and some modules in the `src` folder like `logic` and `utils`.

Now in my code i initialize `os.environ` with some custom variables that i need throughout the project. say `C_1` and `C_2`

this is how i set variable in main.py

```
os.environ.setdefault("C_1", "local-storage")
```

Now i make sure that these variables are getting initalize by `main.py` and then in my `logic` modules there is some `file.py` that call come function from `utils.py` in `utils` modules

But when i am trying to access these variable in that utils function i did not find it.

Instead it throws error that no such variable is available.

My question is i am initalizing the os.environ in the beginning but still i am not able to access these varables in my code. `Why?`

In my function in utils.py

```
 print os.environ
```

All other unnecessary to me variables are there but no `C_1`

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I updated the question for more clarity

Comment: How are you running your application? Are you importing functions from `utils` or running `utils.py` after `main.py` has exited?

Comment: from `main.py` I call `file.py` in my logic module there i perform some dataframe operation. before that i have to read the dataframe from csv. there i call the `utils` function to generate the path of the csv file by appending the local-storage to the provided file name. there i get the issue that C_1 has no value(Empty)